# how to schedule a task at boot time in linux

Tags: linux, boot, cron

I need to know how to schedule a task at boot-time for my linux machine.
I know how to do it in Windows, but I still don't know how to do it in Linux (using Xubuntu).
What I need to do is lauch a web page with firefox at boot time.
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to do what you are asking for. I am going to tell you the easiest one.

Since you are using **Xubuntu**..

1. Open the **Whiskers Menu** from top-left corner or **Application Finder** with Super-R or Windows-R keyboard shortcut.
2. Search for **Session and Startup** and launch it.
3. Switch to the **Application Autostart** tab and click the **+Add** button.
4. Fill the **Name** form with some keyword that is easy to find such as **Firefox Startup Webpage** for example.
5. **Description** is not mandatory but you may fill it with information related to the task.
6. Please enter the following in **Command** form:

   > firefox http://www.example.com
7. You may change the link with the url of the webpage that you want to open in Firefox at boot time.
8. Click the **OK** button to save the task.
9. Restart your computer to check.